# Using NVENC with DirectX 10

Tags: directx, nvenc

I know that it is possible to use DirectX 9 or DirectX 11 surfaces/textures to encode video with NVENC. But how about DirectX 10? Can I initialize encoder with ID3D10Device and use ID3D10Texture2D?

Comment: There's no reason at all to use Direct3D 10. Direct3D 11 provides better support on all platforms where Direct3D 10 is applicable. See [Direct3D 11 Deployment for Game Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3darticles/direct3d11-deployment).

Comment: I know, that Direct3D 11 is better, but I want to know is there an ability to use Direct3D 10 resources to encode with NVENC?

Comment: But *why*? Just use Direct3D 11 and move on

Comment: And why not? It is not the worst version of DirectX API. And there are lot of people, that still use DX10 videocards.

Comment: DirectX 11 the API is not the same thing as the DIrect3D Hardware Feature Level. DX11 supports ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0`` and ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1`` video hardware, as well as older and newer cards. Read [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/). The DirectX 11 API is DirectX 10 but with Device split into Device and DeviceContext. See [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/d3d11-programming-guide-migrating#direct3d-10-to-direct3d-11). Again, there's zero value to using the DirectX 10 API anymore.

Comment: Wow, I don't know that. Thanks a lot! I will convert my code.